# JDBC SQLServerConnection "Login failed for user 'sa'"

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, connection

I am trying connection with database but this error frustrates me . Can anyone help me out what is the problem here?

I want to connect to SQL Server from Eclipse.

```java
public class JDBC_Test {

  public static void SQLServerConnection() {
    try {
      String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=Northwind";
      String user = "sa";
      String password = "832Waseem#";
      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
      System.out.println("Connection Created Successfully.......");
      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from categories");

      while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + " " + rs.getString(2) + " " + rs.getString(3));
      }
      con.close();
      System.out.println("Connection Closed Successfully.......");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // System.out.println("Unable to create Connection reason is as below.......");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SQLServerConnection();

  }
}
```

My Error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'. at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:196)

Comment: Are you sure that is the password of the `sa` account? Is it possible that you have multiple SQL Server instances running, and this is the password of the `sa` account on a different instance?

Comment: No I am not sure. I set this password at the time of installation. Not sure about other instances kindly help?